# Gson issue. My .java file does not accept "import com.google.gson.*;"

Tags: java, maven, gson

I have maven and java installed on my system. When typing "import com.google.gson.Gson;" does not seam to work. See image one or code sample one. [image: Image one]

(code sample one)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

I have been fiddling around with my pom.xml file. I think the problem is somewhat related to the pom.xml file?? See image two or code sample two. plz help, just some pointers would [image: Image two] help i have been searching for hours. [image: Image of my dependencies]

(code sample two)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When running code i get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at TDT4100_project/skibuddies.conditionsAvalanchGetters.WeatherGetter.main(WeatherGetter.java:97)
```

Comment: Hello. Please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) but as formatted text. Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Also your IDE should generate error messages corresponding to each of those red underlines. Please include those errors in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `requires com.google.gson;` in your `module-info.java` file.

Comment: wow, you a wizard man. Thanks